# “When is the last time…?” OR “When was the last time…?”

Tags: grammar

I wonder which one is correct: is, was or either in this following conversation ?

> Henry: I was on the phone for an hour.
>
> Ron: Who were you talking to for an hour?
>
> Henry: Sam, an old friend from college.
>
> Ron: When is the last time you talked to him?
>
> Henry: At college graduation!
>
> Ron: Wow! That was 30 years ago!
>
> Henry: We had a lot of catching up to do.

Also ...

I wonder for the verb form "talked" , is it use -ed or not (in case with tobe was ) ?

> (A) Ron: When was the last time you talked to him?

or

> (B) Ron: When was the last time you talk to him?

this question is continuing from older post

["When is the last time...?" OR "When was the last time...?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133550/when-is-the-last-time-or-when-was-the-last-time?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: When did you talk to him last time?

Answer (score 1):

Only (A) is correct here. "the last time you talk to him" is simply not used.  "last time" puts thsi in the past, and so the present-tense form 'talk" is not used.

By the way, one also does not say "this question is continuing from older post". An article is needed, either "this question is continuing from **an** older post" or "this question is continuing from **the** older post". "The" is better since a specific post is intended and linked to, but "an" would be acceptable.

Comment: thanks for your lessons , i tought verb will be changed to infinitive when be used in question form (talked become talk)...

Comment: also thanks for your correction for add "an" article